# ¿como hago este programa en c++ y con punteros sobre cambio de caracteres?

Tags: c++, punteros

porfavor me pueden ayudar con este programa es que no entiendo los punteros porfavoooor.
Desarrolle un programa que le solicite al usuario una cadena de texto, el programa debe de generar 20 pares de números que representan ubicaciones de caracteres en la cadena que deben ser intercambiados.
ejemplo

Sapo verde

(2,5)

S poaverde

(1 6)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta añadiendo el código que lleves hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la bienvenida :D te agradezco la respuesta, es lo único que he podido hacer del código no entiendo bien los punteros, te agradezco mucho por la ayuda.

Comment: Hice ese código con números aleatorios pero el ejercicio me pide que el usuario los introduzca y además las ubicaciones y no entiendo como hacerlo.